# math.SE is to MathOverflow as stats.SE is to ________

Tags: discussion

My (perhaps incorrect) impression is that few stats.SE regular users specialize in modern research-level statistics and that the website is most appropriate for undergraduate or masters level content, with a largely applied focus.

Is this a widely known and agreed upon assessment? Is it is right, what is the appropriate venue for modern research level statistics? Is it mathoverflow itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Math pages rather an exception, than the rule in the SE ecosystem, aren't they? Engineering, Physics, Biology, Economy, etc sites don't have sister sites.

Comment: Hi, @Tim! That's a good point. I wonder if math is also an exception in terms of having more users who engage in modern research.

Comment: There are some questions (many unanswered!) here that are exceedingly technical.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/how-did-mathematics-end-up-with-two-stack-exchange-sites-while-physics-only-got mathoverflow was created before math stackexchange

Comment: There's only one other site pair in the network separating research-level Q&A from the rest: [cstheory.se] and [cs.se]. Though [networkengineering.se] may be another exception, but it doesn't really have an 'amateur' counterpoint; [su] covers more than just networks.

Answer (score 13):

There really isn't one.  There just hasn't been a perceived need thus far.  You could suggest a new site on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), but we are the site for both applied and research-level statistics.  Note that there is a lot of overlap amongst SE sites.  A question that goes here can often also be on topic on Stack Overflow, Mathematics, Data Science, Artificial Intelligence, Operations Research, Quantitative Finance, Economics, among possibly others.  Math Overflow does have an [`[st.statistics]`](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/st.statistics) tag with 1,666 threads, so I guess people could post there, too.

I'm a bit skeptical, though.  I don't think the proliferation of sites on SE is the best way to organize information.  Also, people often post what they think are research-level questions that really aren't—an example might be the extremely poor use of our [mathematical-statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-statistics) tag.

Comment: I also think Data Science could plausibly be merged into Stats and maybe AI be merged into CS. But we are at the whims of what Stack Exchange Inc wants.

Answer (score 8):

So many people study and apply statistics of some kind that it’s only natural that we would get lots of applied questions.

At the same time, there are excellent statisticians among our ranks, and users should not feel any need to hold back when it comes to posting research-level questions. I personally have posted multiple questions about fairly recent literature, for instance.

[Challenge an ICML Paper](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569036/challenge-an-icml-paper-for-a-given-set-of-probability-predictions-and-a-log-lo)

[Does Multinomial Probability Calibration Consider the Probabilities of the Non-Dominant Classes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/552533/247274)

If there were to be a “Stat Overflow”, it would come from users wanting to separate out the research-level questions from more routine questions, not because Cross Validated lacks the technical acumen to handle research-level questions.

(And “Stat Overflow” would be quite the name for us to use!)